# Problem with understanding floats in c.. Why does it go into infinite loop?

Tags: c, loops, floating-point

I'm try to renew my C knowledge, and i face with the float error.

For example this loop will be infinite:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    for (float i =18000000; i<18000002; i++){
        printf("%f\n", i);
    }
    printf("win\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Why does it work like that?..

Comment: Probably because `18000001` will be rounded down to `18000000`, so it will never reach `18000002` as it's always rounded down after being increased. The reason why this happens is because [IEEE 754 floats have a precision of 6-9 digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) so that 1 might already be outside of that range.

Comment: `
18000000.000000
18000000.000000
18000000.000000
18000000.000000
18000000.000000
18000000.000000
18000000.000000
18000000.000000
18000000.000000
`
right @Blaze, 18000001 has no representation in float world

Comment: @Blaze Sounds like an answer to the question, unless we should simply hammer it as dupe to "why is floating point inaccurate".

Comment: @Lundin, yes I think that dupe fits well.

Comment: This is why you should forget that `float` is a type. Floating point declarations are spelled `double`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `float` has limited precision.  Assuming it's implemented in IEEE754 single precision floating point, it only has 24 bits of precision, or about 7 decimal digits.

The number 18000000 can be represented exactly in this format, but 18000001 cannot, so adding 1 results in the extra bits at the low end being either rounded or truncated resulting in the value 18000000.  So you get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

The nearest IEEE754 `float` to `18000001` is `18000000`. So `i++` is essentially a no-op. Note that `18000002`is also equally near to `18000001`, but the `float` closer to zero is picked in the event of a tie.

(Since `18000000` is an integral type, `i < 18000002` takes place in `float` arithmetic.)